# Getting the start and end angle of arcs

Tags: trigonometry, circles

How do you find the angles of the arc of two points from a starting point to an ending point on the circle with a given direction of clockwise and anti clockwise?

I am having all kind of problems due to the repeating nature of angles.

For an example in the image below, if i get the angles in the range of [0,360] then an arc from quadrant 4 to quadrant 1 anti clockwise would be break.

[image]

Reason it breaks is because if you were to interpolate from 320 to 40 it would be clockwise.

By interpolation i mean this:

```
 startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle) * t  // where t = [0,1]
```

So how do you represent an arc between 2 points with a given direction for all configurations in a simple logical manner - i'm struggling to figure out the logic to easily find the two angles.

I want the final arc data to basically have:

```
CreateArc(StartPoint, TangentDirection, EndPoint)¬

    StartPoint
    StartAngle
    EndPoint
    EndAngle
```

Comment: What would happen if you set `StartAngle = 320` and `EndAngle = 400`?

Comment: I mean that might solve that one particular setup but other setups the same logic would fail depending on direction.

Comment: What do you mean "the same logic"? I asked a simple question about a function with two specific inputs. I didn't say what logic I used to obtain those two inputs.

Comment: Regarding the logic behind my first comment, the idea was that the two angles would be in increasing sequence (such as `StartAngle = 320`, `EndAngle = 400`) for an anticlockwise arc and in decreasing sequence (such as `StartAngle = 40`, `EndAngle = -40`) for a clockwise arc, replacing one of the originally given angles with an equivalent angle if necessary in order to enforce the increasing/decreasing rule. The question was mainly whether it was OK for one of the angles to be outside the range from 0 to 360 in order to get the correct direction.

Comment: On further examination of your examples, I have a doubt whether the errors have anything to do with the the quadrants the angles are in. It seems to me that you are simply getting the counterclockwise arc every single time, no matter whether it is a long arc or a small arc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the red arrow in the figure below is pointing in the direction of `TangentDirection`. There are two cases, one where the result should be a clockwise arc from `StartPoint` to `EndPoint`, the other where the result should be an anticlockwise arc.

[image]

The arc from $A$ to $B$ is anticlockwise. Notice that if the directed line segment from $A$ to $B$ is at an angle $\alpha$ anticlockwise from `TangentDirection`, the central angle of the arc is $2\alpha$ anticlockwise (by a theorem of geometry).

The arc from $A$ to $C$ is clockwise. If the directed line segment from $A$ to $C$ is at an angle $\beta$ clockwise from `TangentDirection`, the central angle of the arc is $2\beta$ clockwise.

In either case, the central angle is twice the angle from `TangentDirection` to the line segment, and in the same direction.

So we first compute the angle from `TangentDirection` to the line segment.
Assuming you're setting all your angle variables to the degree measurements of the angles, we let

```
LineSegmentDirection = direction from StartPoint to EndPoint
AngleFromTangent = LineSegmentDirection - TangentDirection
while (AngleFromTangent < -180) AngleFromTangent = AngleFromTangent + 360
while (AngleFromTangent > 180) AngleFromTangent = AngleFromTangent - 360
AngleOfArc = 2 * AngleFromTangent 
EndAngle = StartAngle + AngleOfArc
```

The purpose of the `while` statements is to ensure that `AngleFromTangent` is between $-180$ and $180$ even if the smallest turn angle from `TangentDirection` to `LineSegmentDirection` crosses the border between the first and fourth quadrants.
For example, if `TangentDirection` is $340$ and `LineSegmentDirection` is $100$ then
`LineSegmentDirection - TangentDirection` will be $-240$, but the first `while` statement will add $360$ and the final result will be $120,$ which is the correct angle from `TangentDirection` to `LineSegmentDirection`.
This is a simple-minded algorithm but is reasonably efficient if `TangentDirection` and `LineSegmentDirection` are within $360$ degrees of each other.
(It will even be OK if they are within $720$ degrees of each other!)

Alternatively, if you have mastered the use of a floating-point "mod" function and can make it give the same results as the two `while` statements, you can use the "mod" function instead of the `while` statements.

Note that we do **not** (most emphatically **not**) apply any such "correction" to the value of `EndAngle`.
That is, if (for example) the code above sets `EndAngle` to 430, then 430 is the value we pass to the function that interpolates the arc.
That's because this value of `EndAngle` is in the correct direction (positive or negative) from `StartAngle` using this value we ensure that all the angles computed by

```
StartAngle + (EndAngle - StartAngle) * t
```

(where $t \in [0,1]$) are also in the correct direction from `StartAngle`.

Comment: Hi sorry for a late follow up to this but i am wondering if you know how to for a given point on the circle check to see if the point is between StartAngle and EndAngle given that the angles are not just within the 0-360 parameters?

Comment: There's more than one way to define whether a point is "between" or "not between" two angles, so you should think about what you mean. If you are just using the angles to identify two points on a circle, and you want to know if the given point is on the shortest arc between those two points, you get one algorithm. If the direction (clockwise or anticlockwise) is also specified, you get a different algorithm that sometimes looks at the shorter arc and sometimes the longer.

Comment: If starting at 400 and ending at 800 means you go all the way around plus 40 degrees, then every point on the circle is "between" the start and end, and there's yet another algorithm to decide the question.

Comment: So this simple-sounding question actually needs a more detailed discussion. For that reason, and because you might get answers from other people as well, I suggest you ask a new question. (Sometimes, when questions are related like these, it also helps to put a link to the old question in the new question.)

Comment: Okay, i will post a new question tomorrow when i get time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pseudo-code:

```
ind = 1; // indicator default is 1
ind = -1  if  "travel distance" is opposite to "parametrization direction";
arcSize = Mod( ind * (StartAngle - EndAngle) , 360); // StartAngle is parametrized from 2-dim vector StartPoint to (0, 2Pi) , same for EndAngle from EndPoint.
```

This should be work for both clockwise and counterclockwise parameterization, just don't forget to apply the definition to the starting point and end point correctly.

<sup>After confirming that this works (meaning that I finally understood the OP correctly), I'll try to clean up the comments (which needs OP's cooperation) as well as make this answer looks nicer.</sup>

Comment: I understand the Mod command. Though if i am then changing direction, do i have to flip the terms to (320-40) = 280 mod 360 ? Either way i get a positive angle, which doesn't make it clear which direction i am travelling in... if i said im going from A to B with an angle difference of 280 or in your answer 80, you would still need to know which direction, clockwise or anticlockwise before you could draw it, right ?

Comment: Well here is another example : https://i.imgur.com/mjFqh4g.png the generated area is not what i wanted, i wanted the red filled area but i got the large arc instead of the minor one. The red vector giving the direction.

Comment: Okay let me try explain a bit better, perhaps i haven't explained well enough. Basically i have a start point with a direction and a some other point on the circle.

The direction tells me which way to go from the start point, to the other point. The problem is when i flip the direction - the arc is incorrect because as you mention you end up with the second arc and not the first arc. So this is a visual where by the red arrow is the direction from the start point:

https://i.imgur.com/xSoOVkU.gif

Watch when i flip the direction, the arc becomes incorrect.

Comment: Just read your edited answer, bit confused by the arcSize as you seem to be applying a modulo to 2D vectors? Did you mean to put start angle and end angle, and if you did mean to use angles, are they in the range of (-pi,pi) or (0,2pi)

Comment: Just tested it and got these results: 

The first one has correct size. but incorrect drawn arc (1) https://i.imgur.com/xen5g4i.jpg

The second one has correct arc, but incorrect size (2) https://i.imgur.com/xen5g4i.jpg

This is the code where i did the math (3) https://hatebin.com/ygbvmshcgb maybe it will help see what i am doing more so seeing the code.

Comment: I'm an idiot i posted the same image twice and can't edit the comment:

Second arc (2) is this https://i.imgur.com/Yy9Wf9s.jpg  Correct arc, wrong size (the opposite of the issues (1) has).

Comment: There are several places I think are problematic, but first try this and see what happens: the mod % should be applied to the whole thing with parenthesis $\mathbf{\color{red} (} \text{Mathf.Sign(dot) * (startangle - endAngle)} \mathbf{\color{red})}\% 360$

Comment: Yeah that fixes the size being negative but it still gives the same size values

Comment: Also, this seems to have become more of a coding problem and not about math concept. Usually this should be done elsewhere (like StackOverflow), and especially should not be done in comments.

Comment: Yeah i think i might ask on SO at this point. :)